# Faster way to convert data frames with dictionaries to numpy arrays

Tags: performance, numpy-ndarray, exploded

I have a table like:

[image]

It can be create with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"cat1":[1,1,1], "cat2":[1,2,3], "config":[json.dumps({"val1":{"a":11, "b":12}, "val2":{"a":21, "b":22}}), json.dumps({"val1":{"a":13, "b":14},"val2":{"a":23, "b":24}}), json.dumps({"val1":{"a":15, "b":16},"val2":{"a":25, "b":26}})]})
```

I need to create 2 numpy arrays (one for "a" and another one for "b") with the columns cat1, cat2 and val1, val2.

For instance numpy array for "a" will be:

```
np.array([[1,1,11,21], [1,2,13,23], [1,3,15,25]])
```

and for "b":

```
np.array([[1,1,12,22], [1,2,14,24], [1,3,16,26]])
```

Is there a way without a loop?

I tried with:

```
a_s=[]; 
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    df_=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json.loads(row["config"]))
    l = df_[df_.index=="a"]
    l["cat1"] = row.cat1
    l["cat2"] = row.cat2
    a_s.append(l)
pd.concat(a_s)
```

But it is not very efficient.

**At the same time it might happen that the dictionaries do not have the same order of keys**, or even the same keys at all (in which case the values should be replaced by 0).

Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Thanks.